# Get all records grouped by field from association and sorted by count in group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have 3 models: `Post`, `Comment`, `User`

`Post` has many `Comments`

`Comment` belongs to `User`

`User` has field `country_code`

I want to get all post comments grouped by country code AND sorted by amount of comments per country.

This query:

```
post.comments.joins(:user).group("users.country_code").order('count_all desc').count
```

returns such kind of result:

```
{"DE"=>67,
"US"=>8,
"RS"=>8,
"IN"=>8,
"ES"=>7,
"BR"=>6,
...
"UA"=>0
```

}

What I need is a similar result where country codes are keys but values are arrays of comments. I don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the group_by that comes with the Ruby enumeration module

```
post.comments.group_by{ |c| c.user.country_code }
```

If you also want it ordered by amount of comments in each group that's also possible:

```
post.comments.group_by{ |c| c.user.country_code }.sort_by{ |k, v| v.length }
```

I suppose to get the sorting in the opposite direction you could multiply the length by `-1` in the sort block.

```
post.comments.group_by{ |c| c.user.country_code }.sort_by{ |k, v| v.length * -1 }
```

Comment: The performance of this could be terrible if the list of comments is large (imaginate a viral facebook post with comments), because group_by loads all the comments in memory from the database. This should be avoided and only be used with fixed known size collections or at least variable with known max size

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this: (Un-tested):

```
post.comments.joins(:users).select("users.country_code, count(1) as count_all").group("users.country_code").order('count_all desc')
```

Answer (score -2):

I think if you use group by the grouping will occur in sql returning an aggregate result which won't have all of the comments. You should include user and then group in ruby. Something like this:

```
post.comments.includes(:users).inject({}){|r, x| r[x.user.country_code].nil? ? r[x.user.country_code] = [x] : r[x.user.country_code] << x;r}
```

Comment: If you use the ActiveRecord method `group` it will aggregate the result as you say, but if you use the completely different Ruby method `group_by` as shown in my answer then it doesn't aggregate, and gives the desired result. Don't use a complicated `inject` block to do the same thing that `group_by` does simply.