# How to get build Rails ActiveRecord query to group objects that belong_to other model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, mysql2

*Given the following models:*

```
ServiceCenter
  has_many :country_codes

CountryCode
  belongs_to :service_center
```

*What is the ActiveRecord query that will return something like this:*

```
{
  "US": ["United States"],
  "PT": ["Portugal", "Spain", "Estonia"],
  "FR": ["France", "Germany", "Austria"]
}
```

*where the keys are the `country` attribute of each ServiceCenter and the values are the `country_name` attributes of each CountryCode that belongs to it?* In other words, I want just a list of which CountryCodes belong to each ServiceCenter, showing only those attributes.

```
{ 'service_centers.country': 'country_code.country_name', 'country_code.country_name' }
```

I have tried this:

`CountryCode
  .joins(:service_center)
  .select('country_codes.country_name', 'service_centers.country')
  .group('service_centers.country')`

but this returns:

```
<ActiveRecord::Relation [
  <CountryCode id: nil, country_name: "Portugal">,
  <CountryCode id: nil, country_name: "United States">,
  <CountryCode id: nil, country_name: "Portugal">.....]>
```

I also tried `ServiceCenter.joins(:country_code)....` but similar result - an ActiveRecord Relation with ServiceCenter objects whose ids were nil, and whose `country` attributes were given.

I've looked at answers similar to this one: [Get all records grouped by field from association and sorted by count in group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32254473/get-all-records-grouped-by-field-from-association-and-sorted-by-count-in-group), but I don't want a count.

I would appreciate any help with this!!

Comment: It's hard to achieve completely in mysql database, it has no array/hstore datatype (like in postgresql), so you can't do transformations to hash-like data structure.

Comment: Ah, maybe that's what I'm missing. I have this feeling that I KNOW it's possible and I've seen something like this before, but it was probably w/ Postgresql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not recommended to get all records like below, as it'll have optimisation issue. But, for you understanding, you may try:

```
hash = {}

ServiceCenter.all.each do |service_center|
  hash[service_center.country] = service_center.country_codes.pluck(:country_name)
end
```

the output `hash` would be like, eg:

```
{
  "US": ["United States"],
  "PT": ["Portugal", "Spain", "Estonia"],
  "FR": ["France", "Germany", "Austria"]
}
```

**Note:** Hash can't have multiple values as you have specified, it should be in the form of Array.

**EDIT**

Not exactly what you want, but this may help a bit:

```
ServiceCenter.joins(:country_codes).group("service_center_id").pluck("service_centers.country, GROUP_CONCAT(country_codes.country_name)")
```

**Output**

```
[["US", "United States"], ["PT", "Portugal, Spain, Estonia"], ["FR", "France, Germany, Austria"]]
```

Comment: Thanks @Abhi. Yeah, I considered doing it just with Ruby, but I'm specifically wondering if there is a way to do it with ActiveRecord. You mentioned an optimisation issue - are you thinking of memory or time? What would the optimisation benefit be with Ruby vs. Arel?

Comment: Oh, nevermind the optimization question - I misread it before. I see what you mean. Calling `.each` on `ServiceCenter.all.includes(:country_codes)` would make it a bit more performant.

Comment: It does, thanks! I didn't know about GROUP_CONCAT - very useful in this case.